# List of built-in Sitecore Field Types

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype

Sitecore provides a large number of fields out of the box, and while some of them are obvious (Checkbox, Single Line Text, ...) some fields are not obvious by name alone (eg. What is Droplist vs Droplink).

Is there a listing for all the field types built into Sitecore, with an example of how they are rendered within the Content Editor?

Comment: There used to be something like that in the documentation for Sitecore 6.x. I did not see any promising articles in a quick search on https://doc.sitecore.net/SearchResults#query=field%20types.

They could be inspected with something like DotPeek.

Comment: There is a pdf that has the field types on the old SDN as Daniel said. It is under the version 6 documentation.
https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Data%20Definition%20Reference.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found an older post on Sitecore fieldtypes and the way they are rendered in a blogpost. It's not the complete list, but a starting point:

http://www.mtelligent.com/home/2014/8/29/sitecore-field-type-overview-reference.html